# how to disable a option of a select box in ie 7

Tags: html

```
   <option value="07.00" disabled="disabled">07.00 P.M</option>
```

This is not working in IE-7 rest working in all the browsers...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot disable individual options on IE7 – only the whole select.

There seems to be some kind of hack available, though:

- http://elmicoxcodes.blogspot.com/2007/05/activating-option-disabled-in-ie.html