# IE javascript / jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get these 2 select drop downs to work which basically rely on each other for out of stock. The idea is that out of stock combination would be disabled from the user selection. This works fine in all browsers except IE.

I found a script for IE which basically adds disabled class and does an alert pop up and then resets the select dropdown.

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/osipe5/2

In that, please select size as 1X. As you can see everything works perfectly. We are good. Now select size 2X. In the color dropdown "White" has the disabled class. That is not correct. The issue is somewhere with ieLessThan8OptionDisable()

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: jQuery abstracts all those nasty cross-browser discrepancies away. **Why** are you writing browser-specific code with jQuery?

Comment: jQuery does not and cannot fix the disable problem in select dropdowns. There are other work arounds like this one but nothing can disable an option which is a feature that doesn't exist in IE6 or IE7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is this line in `ieLessThan8OptionDisable()`:

```
this.blur();
```

Change it to `$(this).blur();`. But seriously, please stop writing browser-specific code with jQuery.

---

Since you're running into a common IE pre-8 bug, you might want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280010/how-to-disbale-a-option-of-a-select-box-in-ie-7).

Comment: @Matt Ball: Thanks but thats not the issue. I have removed that code and tried and it still doesn't work the way it should. The reason to write browser specific code is that I do not want IE users to select an option which should be disabled. Unfortunately with IE6 and IE7 that's possible. Hence the reason for writing IE specific code.

Comment: I have updated the changes with your recommended improvement: http://jsbin.com/osipe5/2

Comment: @Eddy: your second link seems to have the expected behavior in IE 6. What's the problem now?

Comment: @Matt Ball: Are you not seeing the problem when you select 2X from the size drop and the color "White" has the disabled class? "White" shouldn't be a disabled class

Comment: @Eddy: I don't see that problem - however, I the issue is this: instead of testing `if (disabled) { ... } ` you need to test `if (disabled.length) { ... }`. See [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_test_whether_an_element_exists.3F) for more. Also, there is really no need to swap out the `disabled` attribute for a `disabled` class.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Perfect! I did find another small issue with my `if (inArray(oos,optcheck)) { .. } else { .. }` Basically I need to removeClass of disabled from previous selection of size box.

Comment: @Matt Ball: By the way I need the "disabled" class for styling purposes so I added that back.